# Как изменить Y?

Tags: c++, математика

Дано двузначное число .Если сумма его цифр кратна , а первая цифра меньше , уменьшить все его цифры на 5 (по модулю); если сумма его цифр кратна , а первая цифра больше , увеличить все его цифры на 5 (по модулю 10); если сумма его цифр не кратна , а первая цифра меньше , уменьшить все его цифры на 4 (по модулю); если сумма его цифр не кратна , а первая цифра больше , увеличить все его цифры на 4 (по модулю 10); в остальных случаях—увеличить все его цифры на 2 (по модулю 10).На экран вывести новое число, а не набор цифр.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
using namespace std;
 int main() 
 {
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
     int A, X,y1,Y;
     cout << "Введите двузначное число\n";
     cin >> A;
     cout << "Введите однозначное число\n";
     cin >> X;
     //проверка на корректный ввод
     if (A < 10 || A > 99 || X <= 0 || X > 9) cout << "Неправильно введены данные\n";
     else { //все хорошо
         int b = A / 10;
         int c = A % 10;
         int S = b + c;
         int bn, cn, y1;
         if (S % X == 0 && bn < y1)
         { //сумма кратна X
             if (c % X == 0)
             { //вторая цифра кратна X
                 bn = abs((b - 5));
                 cn = abs((c - 5));
             }
             else { //первая цифра не кратна X
                 bn = b * 2 % 10;
                 cn = c * 2 % 10;

             }

         }

         if (S % X == 0 && bn > y1)
         { //сумма кратна X
             if (c % X == 0)
             { //вторая цифра кратна X
                 bn = (b + 5) % 10;
                 cn = (c + 5) % 10;

             }
             else { //первая цифра не кратна X
                 bn = b * 2 % 10;
                 cn = c * 2 % 10;

             }

         }

         else { //сумма не кратна X
             if (c % X == 0 && bn < y1) 
             { //вторая цифра кратна X
                 bn = (b + 5) % 10;
                 cn = (c + 5) % 10;

             }
             { //первая цифра не кратна X
                 bn = abs((b - 4));
                 cn = abs((c - 4));


             }

         }
         if (S % X == 0 && bn > y1)
         { //сумма кратна X
             if (c % X == 0)
             { //вторая цифра кратна X
                 bn = (b + 5) % 10;
                 cn = (c + 5) % 10;

             }
             else { //первая цифра не кратна X
                 bn = b * 2 % 10;
                 cn = c * 2 % 10;

             }

         }
         else 
             { //сумма не кратна X
                 if (c % X == 0 && bn > y1)
                 { //вторая цифра кратна X
                     bn = (b + 5) % 10;
                     cn = (c + 5) % 10;

                 }
                 { //первая цифра не кратна X
                     bn = abs((b + 4));
                     cn = abs((c + 4));

                 }

             }
         Y = 10 * bn + cn; //создаем новое число
         cout << Y << endl;
        
    }
     system("pause");
     return 0;
    
}
```

Дал весь код чтобы потом не было вопросов.Можете помочь пожалуйста с реализацией задачи верно?

Comment: судя по условию задачи необходимы: число A, цифра X, цифра Y -  а у вас вижу ввод только A и X - а Y куда дели?

Comment: int A, X,y1,Y у меня в этой строчке Y задаётся @Zhihar

Comment: у вас нигде y1 ничем не инициализируется и Y, что в них за значение по вашему?

Comment: Хорошо,а как мне проверять первая цифра больше или меньше y?У меня же задача ввести трёхзначное X и вывести Y по правилам описанным в условии @Zhihar

Comment: тогда я не понимаю условие задачи - в том условии, что вы привели совокупность правил для работы с числом А и цифрами X, Y - Это три внешних параметра, которые вводит пользователь. А у вам кроме того переменная y1 **не определена!!!**, а значит все условия и действия с ней будут выдавать мусор

Comment: Я убрал y1 совсем из программы и заменил его на b.Программа работает,но вот правильно ли....
Вот что у меня вышло
```
if (A < 10 || A > 99 || X <= 0 || X > 9) cout << "Неправильно введены данные\n";
  else { //все хорошо
   int b = A / 10;
   int c = A % 10;
   int S = b + c;
   int bn, cn;
   if (S % X == 0 && b < A)
   { //сумма кратна X
    if (c % X == 0)
    { //вторая цифра кратна X
     bn = abs((b - 5));
     cn = abs((c - 5));
    }
    else { //первая цифра не кратна X
     bn = b * 2 % 10;
     cn = c * 2 % 10;

    }

   }

```
@Zhihar

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115531/discussion-between--and-zhihar).

Comment: приведите новый код

Comment: @Zhihar y1 определена во второй строке main-а

Comment: @Billy, `int A, X,y1,Y;` это? и чему же оно равно? ну ок, "определено, но не инициализировано"

Comment: @Zhihar определено, инициализировано, но значение indeterminate

Comment: Скажите, а что за странный вопрос - **Как изменить Y**? При том, что нигде такая задача - изменять Y - не ставится? Почему бы тогда не озаглавить вопрос "Как озаглавить вопрос?" - при поиске по сайту всем все сразу будет понятно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окей,я написал программу верную,спустя 4 часа))Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
int A, X, Y, result; // объявлем переменные
cout «"Введите двузначное число A" « endl;
cin » A; //вводим двухзначное число
cout « "Введите число X" « endl;
cin » X; // вводим число Х
cout « "Введите число Y" «endl;
cin » Y; // вводим число Y

//проверяем правильность введеных значений, иначе ввыводим сообщение об ошибке
if (A < 10 || A > 99 || X <= 0 || X > 9|| Y<=0 || Y> 9)
{
cout « "Некорректный ввод" « endl;
}

else
{

// делением и нахождением остатка от деления получаем цифры по отдельности введеного числа
int A1 = A / 10; // первая цифра числа
int A2 = A % 10; // вторая цифра числа
int sum = A1 + A2;
//ход решения проверка условий

//проверка 1 условия задачи
if ((sum % X == 0) && (A1 < Y))
{
A1 = abs((A1 - 5))* 10;
A2 = abs(A2 - 5);
result = A1 + A2;
}

//если сумма кратна , а первая меньше , увеличить число  на 5
else if ((sum % X == 0) && (A1 >Y))
{
A1 = ((A1 + 5)) % 10 * 10;
A2 = (A2 + 5) % 10;
result = A1 + A2;
}

//если сумма не кратна , а первая меньше , уменьшить число  на 4
else if ((sum % X != 0) && (A1 <Y))
{
A1 = ((A1 - 4)) % 10 *10 ;
A2 = (A2 - 4) % 10 ;
result = A1 + A2;
}
else if ((sum % X != 0) && (A1 >Y))
{
A1 = ((A1 + 4)) % 10 * 10;
A2 = (A2 + 4) % 10;
result = A1 + A2;
}


//остальные случаи увеличить число А на 2
else
{
A1 = abs((A1 + 2)) % 10 *10;
A2 = abs(A2 + 2) % 10;
result = A1 + A2;
}
//вывод результата программы, нового преобразованного числа
cout « "Результат " « result « endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вы не сообразили, что вычитать 5 по модулю 10 - то же самое, что и прибавить 5 по модулю? А вычесть 4 - что и прибавить 6...

Answer (score 2):

Вы опять?

```
int Result(int A, int X, int Y) {
    int R;
    int sumA = A % 10 + A / 10;

    // Если сумма его цифр кратна X, а первая цифра меньше Y
    // если сумма его цифр кратна X, а первая цифра больше Y
    if (sumA % X == 0 && A / 10 != Y) R = 5;
    else // если сумма его цифр не кратна X, а первая цифра меньше Y
        if (sumA % X != 0 && A / 10 < Y)  R = 6;
        else // если сумма его цифр не кратна X, а первая цифра больше Y
            if (sumA % X != 0 && A / 10 > Y)  R = 4;
            else R = 2;

    return ((A / 10 + R) % 10) * 10 + (A % 10 + R) % 10;
    }
```

Можете перед использованием сами проверить двузначность A и т.д.